# Domain of a function with radical

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

I want to find the domain of the following function
$$f(x)=\frac{2x-3}{\sqrt{x^2-5x+4}}$$
Please give me a hint.

Answer (score 1):

The domain is the set of all possible $x$-values which will make the function "work", and will output real $y$-values. Hence, the denominator cannot take the value of $0$. That is, $x^{2}-5x+4 \neq 0$. So, $x$ cannot belong to {$-1,4$}. Also the denominator $(x-1)(x-4)$ should be greater than $0$. That is x should not belong to $(1,4)$. The intersection of these two sets gives us the resultant $$x \in \mathbb R -[1,4]$$

Comment: I will fix it right now.

Comment: @Arthur Corrected. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. The argument of the square-root should be $\geq 0$. Moreover the denominator should be $\not=0$. So you should solve
$$x^{2}-5x+4>0.$$

Can you take it form here?